# Is there a simple to use library to play music (or get line in) and out put spectrum analysis values?

Tags: .net, audio, visualization

I am trying to get the values that generate the following:
[image]

In my research I've seen several libraries (NAudio seems the most powerful I've looked at so far) that supposedly get these values, but I haven't the first clue how to do it.

Essentially I want to poll these values while music is playing, to create animations based on them.

However in everything I've searched for, it seems like I'm going to have to do a lot of work just to get these values?

Is there any library that simplifies this process, or any example code/projects that show how to make the above, so I can just take the values and apply them to what I'm trying to do?

I'm not trying to understand how these values are created or retrieved, just would like to have them so I can make use of them. (Assuming that these lines reference different frequencies in each sample(?) of the music).

Low frequencies cause one animation, higher frequencies cause different animations is what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Check this [Multimedia PeakMeter Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/PeakMeterCS.aspx?display=Print), There are three projects in the source code, and shows the example of spectral analysis of audio.

Comment: Make that an answer, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On @Aequitarum's suggestion adding my comment as answer.**

Check this [Multimedia PeakMeter Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/PeakMeterCS.aspx?display=Print) There are three projects in the source code, and shows the example of spectral analysis of audio.

Comment: Thanks, took me 5 minutes to get the values I needed using this program. meterData array has them all easily accessible!